# Error : Cannot find Module 'fabric-client' in fabric 1.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, npm-install

Even after trying "npm update" command, still i am facing fabric-client error. The error details given below

Fabric version - 1.2 |
OS - Amazon Linux2 |
command -  npm i

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-27 controller]# node app.js
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'fabric-client'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/AWSNodeApp/controller/app.js:27:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
```

Below is the content of package.json

```
{
  "name": "awsnodeapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.538.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.3",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.2",
    "fabric-ca-client": "1.3.0",
    "fabric-client": "1.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^2.0.0",
    "log4js": "^3.0.6",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "ws": "^6.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the kind of error you get if you haven't actually downloaded your project dependencies with `npm install` prior to running your application. Or have not included a dependency required by your code in your project's `package.json`. Or possibly the `npm install` failed to download the dependencies due to connectivity issues accessing the npm registry. Either way, if you don't have a `node_modules/fabric-client` directory within your project directory, you haven't downloaded your required dependency.

The **fabric-client@1.2** package definitely exists: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric-client/v/1.2.2

Note that this version of Hyperledger Fabric is obsolete. As of today (August 2020), you really should be using v1.4 or (ideally) v2.2. Note that the Node SDK has changed with the v2.2 release and, although the v1.4 **fabric-client** package will still work with a v2.2 Fabric, it is recommended to use **fabric-network@2.2**: https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/tutorial-migration.html

Comment: Yes, you are correct, node_modules/fabric-client folder is missing.I have updated the question with package.json. Not able to figure out why folder is not getting downloaded.

Comment: The version you are targeting seems to have changed but regardless, I see that fabric-client version with `npm view fabric-client@1.3.0`. So the problem is either that it's failing to download, or perhaps some native compilation of the transient dependencies is failing and breaking the install. Look at the `npm install` output to see what happened.

Answer (score 0):

fabric client module is not installed in your project. try this command to install fabric-client module

npm i fabric-client

Comment: Thanks for reply, we tried it, but it is not downloading node_modules/fabric-client directory.